# When PIL is converting an RBG image in the form of a numpy array to a png it delivers an odd result

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert this .tif file to a .png, here is the image (I attached a link because it is 250mb): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nEvG8O5NM1bsKM-fSo66QJF7mZyR_fh-/view?usp=sharing

Here is my current code, it returns an grayscale image with multiple copies of the original .tif in one .png, it is suppose to return an RGB image:

```
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

dataset = rasterio.open("world.tif")
window = rasterio.windows.Window(0, 0, 21600, 10800)
out = dataset.read(window=window)
out = out.reshape(10800, 21600, 3).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(out, "RGB")
img.save("out.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are mixing up **PIL/Pillow** and `raster` like that. You can just do the following with **PIL**:

```
from PIL import Image

# Allow monster large images
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

# Load image
im = Image.open('world.tif')

# Reduce to manageable size and save as PNG
small = im.resize((2160,1080))
small.save('result.png')
```

[image]